# count number of unique occurrence of each value in 1st or 2nd column and print in 3rd column

Tags: sybase-sql-anywhere

```
SELECT
    domain_Job.statusCode as "Status Code",
    lookup_JobStatusCode.name as "Status Code Description"
    FROM
    domain_Job, domain_Client, lookup_JobStatusCode, domain_MasterServer, lookup_JobType, lookup_JobState
    WHERE
    domain_Job.type = lookup_JobType.id AND
    domain_Job.statusCode > 1 AND
    domain_Job.statusCode = lookup_JobStatusCode.id AND
    domain_Job.id = domain_Job.ParentJobID AND
    domain_Job.state = lookup_JobState.id AND
    domain_Job.clientName = domain_Client.name AND
    DATEDIFF(hour,UTCBigIntToNomTime(domain_Job.endTime), GETDATE()) <=24 AND
    domain_Job.policyName != ''
    GROUP BY domain_Job.statusCode, lookup_JobStatusCode.name, domain_MasterServer.networkName, lookup_JobType.name, lookup_JobState.name
```

output :

```
Status Code |   Status Code Description
47          | host is unreachable 
7648        | - 
96          | unable to allocate new media for backup, storage unit has none available 
191         | no images were successfully processed 
806         | this mpx group is unjoinable 
47          | host is unreachable 
7648        | - 
156         | snapshot error encountered 
20          | invalid command parameter 
4234        | VMware server login failure
```

Comment: can someone help paste my output in table and help with query with desired output.

Comment: Use your query as a subquery. Group and count in outer query.

Comment: can you help me with query

Comment: Sybase SQL Anywhere knows about window version of COUNT() function. Add `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY domain_Job.statusCode) AS "Count"` to output fields list.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    domain_Job.statusCode as "Status Code",
    lookup_JobStatusCode.name as "Status Code Description",
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY domain_Job.statusCode) as "Count"
FROM
    domain_Job, domain_Client, lookup_JobStatusCode, domain_MasterServer, lookup_JobType, lookup_JobState
WHERE
    domain_Job.type = lookup_JobType.id AND
    domain_Job.statusCode > 1 AND
    domain_Job.statusCode = lookup_JobStatusCode.id AND
    domain_Job.id = domain_Job.ParentJobID AND
    domain_Job.state = lookup_JobState.id AND
    domain_Job.clientName = domain_Client.name AND
    DATEDIFF(hour, UTCBigIntToNomTime(domain_Job.endTime), GETDATE()) <= 24 AND
    domain_Job.policyName != ''
GROUP BY domain_Job.statusCode, lookup_JobStatusCode.name, domain_MasterServer.networkName, lookup_JobType.name, lookup_JobState.name

Status Code | Status Code Description                  | Count
-------------------------------------------------------------
47          | host is unreachable                     | 2
7648        | -                                      | 2
96          | unable to allocate new media for backup | 1
191         | no images were successfully processed   | 1
806         | this mpx group is unjoinable            | 1
20          | invalid command parameter               | 1
4234        | VMware server login failure             | 1
```